# Session and viewstate at facebook platform

Tags: session, facebook, viewstate

I have an application in facebook platform (a trial application) and i am using session and viewstate in the code of the application and when incrementing the session value it doesn't feel with changes in sometimes, i mean that i store a number in session and on posting back i increment this session value numner with one and when get the new value it is the same as the previous and no changes in the session value so is there any confliction with facebook platform in using session and viewstate ? 
my application is at the following link [Facebook Application](http://apps.facebook.com/hanggame/) and the questions asked in the game is repeated inspit i increment the session so h can i fix this problem please

Note: My application is developed with C# under .Net 2008

Thanks in advance for any reply and attention with my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are writing an IFRAME facebook application.  Does it only happen in IE?

See the section 'Solution to an IE gotcha when developing Facebook App in an IFRAME' on here:
http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/ASP.NET

Comment: Yes i am using iframe application and this is happened in IE and firefox but more in IE

Comment: did u try the solution on the facebook wiki?  you need to add a p3p header in your prerender: Response.AppendHeader("P3P", "CP=\"CAO PSA OUR\"");

Comment: I haven't tried that in wiki but did u face or hear about this problem b4? i will try adding header but tell me where to put it exactly please and thanks in advance for any answer

Comment: take the prerender code from the wiki, and add it to your asp.net code-behind.

Comment: excuse me how can i get the prerender code from wiki ? can u give me a URL for this code or describe to me exactly what to do as really it holds everything in my application   
thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks Mr.Russau i have got this code in the link u passed to me thanks alot for ur g8 effort

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhh
it doesn't work also i have append the prerender code and nothing happend as the problem of session and viewstate face me in firefox and IE so i think that it's a problem in facebook platform not in the IE or firefox